# What is "JTI/Suspect.131328" from McAfee?

Tags: virus, antivirus

Using McAfee Endpoint Security 10.6 on Windows 10 it is the second time I got the:

[image]

Warning.

I cannot find anything related to it while Googling around: "JTI/Suspect.131328"

The question: is this a false alert? Or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support question for the vendor. And since no actual context is known one can only speculate if this is a false alert or not.

Comment: I googled "McAfee JTI/Suspect.131328" and the top 5 hits all answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

McAfee's *Rule Identifier* 131328 is described in [KB82925](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB82925) on *How to identify what rule corresponds to an Adaptive Threat Protection and Threat Intelligence Exchange event*:

> **Detect use of long `-encodedcommand` powershell**
>
> Alerts on variations of the encodedcommand [base64] powershell usage
>
> WMI provides a way of executing code or moving laterally in an
>   environment. Some legitimate software may use this way, so this rule
>   should be behavior in your environment

It may or may not be harmful. That's why it's *suspicious*. Further investigation would require catching and decoding the base64 encoded PowerShell command and analyzing whether it's legitimate use or not.